# Reverted GWT version, now it won't run

Tags: eclipse, gwt

**I already solved this question, this Q&A is purely for future Googlers since it was extremely difficult for me to find the solution via Google - but thanks for looking**

I changed my project to GWT 2.3.0 but then had to change back to 2.0.3 (in Eclipse) and now when I run it and try to view it in my browser, I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Invalid version number "2.1" passed to external.gwtOnLoad(), expected "2.0"; your hosted mode bootstrap file may be out of date; if you are using -noserver try recompiling and redeploying your app

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding and that doesn't work. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your war directory you should have a folder named after your module. Stop debugging if it's running, then delete that module folder (not the entire war folder). Run again; the module folder will be recreated and the error will no longer occur.

Comment: It worked for me but after that I had to clean the browser cache. If it does not works clean browser cache and try again

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Changed `$hostedHtmlVersion="2.1";` to `$hostedHtmlVersion="2.0";` in `hosted.html` file and it worked for me

Comment: If you hit some code that made use of a feature that was changed between versions 2.0.3 and 2.3.0 (or whatever two GWT versions you switched between), I expect it would not work and would likely crash or do something unexpected (since you're using the same compiled code and just tricking it into thinking it was compiled with the old version). It's probably best to clean the directory as I described so that you don't have the possibility of encountering this scenario.